# How to get data from last number and still before space in javascript using regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex

This is my problem below

```
var id = "10101-Building and Construction  21";
```

Basically, I have got id's data from other calculation , i want to separate to 21.

Here result will be 21;

How can i remove id's value without 21 .

Please any help?

Comment: Can't you make that other calculation return something more meaningful than a string?

Comment: Are you looking to grab the last numeric value after a space (ie, `21` in your example above)? Will the data always be in that same format where the last numeric value is of interest?

Comment: `id = id.replace('10101-Building and Construction', '')` :)

Comment: @adeneo: Better `id.substring(33)` then :-)

Comment: @Bergi - Good one! It was a joke, but I see someone has posted it as an answer!

Comment: Basically id data will come dynamically and length is not fixed so, i need from last to still before space . any suggestion

Comment: Basically id data will come dynamically and length is not fixed so, i need from last to still before space . any suggestion , Anthony , adeneo, Bergi

Comment: @MD.ABDULHalim Is there a special format your data being returned will follow? Are all values delimited by a `space`? If so, you won't need regular expression as an example @Bergi posted above should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe combining substring and lastindexOf, something like:

```
var result = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf(' ')+1);
```

Comment: your code is not work , please another suggestion ? here id will come dynamically and not fixed it's length so i need from last to still before space.

Comment: This code extract the part of the id located after the last space (blankspace), i can show you width a fiddle if needed, can you explain why doesn't it fit your needs so as i can eventually modify it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var id = 10101-Building and Construction  21;
var result=id.substring(id.Length-2,id.Length)
});
```

Comment: Basically id data will come dynamically and length is not fixed so, i need from last to still before space . any suggestion

Comment: id will come dynamically and not fixed it's length so i need from last to still before space

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions made based on your question :**

**- The id you wana extact from the string is always at the last**
  **- The id is always a number**

- If above assumptions are true :
- then you can write a javascript function and perform the following functions.

  1. loops from the last and check for numbers till it finds a string
  2. as soon as it encouters a character it stops and you get the requiered id

the function in javascript

```
function express()
{
var str="10101-Building and Construction  21";
var temp,id;
for(var t2=1;t2<=str.length;t2++)
{
    temp = str.substring(str.length-t2);

    var condition = isNaN(temp);
    if(condition == true)
    {
        break;
    }
    id=temp;
}
document.write("<br>"+id);
}
```

this will extract the id

and the `result:`

id = 12

[**Click Here** : And the fiddle for a live example of this based on your values](http://jsfiddle.net/q9Q6M/)